# understanding 2D DFT

Tags: python, numpy, dft

It would be the good aid if one understand the 2D DFT calculation using matrix property. Therefore, I try to implement it using python. The Code is shown below.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


def compute_dft_1(img):
    img_array = np.array(img, dtype=float)
    global M, N
    (M, N) = img_array.shape
    m = np.arange(M)
    n = np.arange(N)
    k, l = np.meshgrid(m, n)
    e1 = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * ((m * k / M) + (n * l / N)))
    sum_terms = np.dot(e1, data_array)
    return sum_terms

img_a = Image.open("image.png")
compute_dft_1(img_a)
```

The computational results, however, is totally different form the true result (I checked it with numpy.fft.fft2). I've put effort to check what part of code is wrong but Ican not find it. Could you help me identify the problem?

Comment: What result are you getting and what result are you expecting?

Comment: Please don't use an image we don't have. You can compare the results using a small matrix (e.g. 4x4 or something) instead of an image.

Comment: You should not compute the 2D DFT this way. The DFT is separable. Compute a 1D DFT along the columns of the matrix, and then along the rows of the result. It does not matter if you do rows or columns first.